# Hook to switch the linter binaries in Emacs Lisp according to virtual environment

Tags: elisp

## Problem

I use Emacs for Python development along with several linters. When I activate a Python virtual environment (venv) from within Emacs, I would like to set the linter binaries according to the following rules:

1. If the venv has a particular linter installed, use it
2. If the venv does not have a particular linter, use the one in a pre-specified, default venv
3. If the linter does not exist in either the active venv or the default venv, set the linter binary to `nil`

For example, let's say I activate a venv called `my_venv` that has `pylint` installed, but no `flake8`. `flake8` is however installed in my default `linters` venv. After activating `my_venv`, the linters that will be used are

- pylint -- my_venv
- flake8 -- linters

#### Purpose

The reason for implementing this is that I develop Python on multiple machines that share a single, version-controlled `init.el` file. I do not want to guarantee that I have the same Python binaries and venvs across these machines; this implementation helps decouple my Emacs setup from the Python venvs that are present on a machine.

#### Additional info

- The code will go inside my `init.el` file
- I use [flycheck](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/) as the interface between Emacs and the linters
- I use [pyvenv](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv) for Python virtual environments in Emacs

## Code

```
(defvar linter-execs '((flycheck-python-flake8-executable "bin/flake8")
                       (flycheck-python-pylint-executable "bin/pylint")
                       (flycheck-python-pycompile-executable "bin/python")))
(defvar default-linter-venv-path (concat (getenv "WORKON_HOME") "/linters/"))

(defun switch-linters ()
  "Switch linter executables to those in the current venv.

If the venv does not have any linter packages, then they will be
set to those in the `default-linter-venv-path` venv.  If these do
not exist, then no linter will be set."
  (dolist (exec linter-execs)
    (let ((venv-linter-bin    (concat pyvenv-virtual-env (nth 1 exec)))
          (default-linter-bin (concat default-linter-venv-path (nth 1 exec)))
          (flycheck-var       (nth 0 exec)))
      (cond ((file-exists-p venv-linter-bin)
             (set flycheck-var venv-linter-bin))
            ((file-exists-p default-linter-bin)
             (set flycheck-var default-linter-bin))
            (t (set flycheck-var nil))))))

(add-hook 'pyvenv-post-activate-hooks 'switch-linters)
```

#### Explanation

- `linter-execs` is a list of two-element lists. The first element of an entry is the `flycheck` variable that contains the path of a linter binary. The second element is the relative path of the binary from within the venv.
- The default linter venv is `$WORKON_HOME/linters`
- `switch-linters` is the call-back function attached to `pyvenv-post-activate-hooks`
- The conditional checks for the presence of the linter binary files, first in the current venv and next in the default venv. Failing these, it sets the binary to `nil` in the line `(t (set flycheck-var nil))`

## Specific questions

- Is this idiomatic elisp, or is it too "Pythonic"?
- Is `linter-execs` the proper way to implement a list of tuples in elisp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It would be a good idea to write a docstring for the `defvar`'d variables like `linter-execs`. The explanations in the post would make an excellent start, for example:

   ```
   (defvar linter-execs '((flycheck-python-flake8-executable "bin/flake8")
                          (flycheck-python-pylint-executable "bin/pylint")
                          (flycheck-python-pycompile-executable "bin/python"))
     "The linter executables, as list of two-element lists. The
   first element of an entry is the flycheck variable that contains
   the path of a linter executable. The second element is the
   relative path of the executable from within the venv.")
   ```
2. Writing `(nth 0 exec)` and `(nth 1 exec)` makes it hard to understand the meaning of these items of data. In Python you'd use tuple unpacking to give meaningful names to each element of the `exec` data structure, like this:

   ```
   flycheck_var, path = exec
   ```

   In Emacs Lisp you can use [`cl-destructuring-bind`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Macros.html) in a similar way:

   ```
   (dolist (exec linter-execs)
     (cl-destructuring-bind (flycheck-var path) exec
       (let ((venv-linter-bin    (concat pyvenv-virtual-env path))
         ;; etc
   ```

   But `exec` comes from a list that you are looping over, so you could use the [`cl-loop`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Loop-Facility.html) macro instead of `dolist`, and `cl-loop` has destructuring built in:

   ```
   (cl-loop for (flycheck-var path) in linter-execs do
     (let ((venv-linter-bin    (concat pyvenv-virtual-env path))
       ;; etc
   ```

   You'll need `(require 'cl-macs)` to use `cl-destructuring-bind` or `cl-loop`.
3. The two directories `pyvenv-virtual-env` and `default-linter-venv-path` are treated in exactly the same way: first we do `(let ((Y (concat X path))` and then `(file-exists-p Y)` and finally `(set flycheck-var Y)`. This repetition could be factored out into a loop:

   ```
   (defun switch-linters ()
     "Switch linter executables to those in the current venv.

   If the venv does not have any linter packages, then they will be
   set to those in the `default-linter-venv-path` venv.  If these do
   not exist, then the linter will be set to nil."
     (cl-loop with dirs = (list pyvenv-virtual-env default-linter-venv-path)
              for (flycheck-var path) in linter-execs
              do (set flycheck-var
                      (cl-loop for directory in dirs
                               for executable = (concat directory path)
                               if (file-exists-p executable) return executable)))
   ```
4. Instead of [`file-exists-p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Testing-Accessibility.html), you probably want to use [`file-executable-p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Testing-Accessibility.html).
5. Looking for a file in a list of directories is built into Emacs as the function [`locate-file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Locating-Files.html). Using this, we get:

   ```
   (defun switch-linters ()
     "Switch linter executables to those in the current venv.

   If the venv does not have any linter packages, then they will be
   set to those in the `default-linter-venv-path` venv.  If these do
   not exist, then the linter will be set to nil."
     (cl-loop with dirs = (list pyvenv-virtual-env default-linter-venv-path)
              for (flycheck-var path) in linter-execs
              do (set flycheck-var (locate-file path dirs nil 'file-executable-p))))
   ```